# Improve silk cloth material when falling

Tags: materials, physics

I have generated a material (from my last post) and animated it to fall on and then slip off a green screen picture frame, but the material seems to have poor edges and does not seem realistic in its movement.

Are there any improvements I could make to this using Blender?

Anim: https://youtu.be/a8PlEGQZ4Lo

Blender settings:
[image: Material shader nodes]

[image: Green screen nodes (is there a way to remove light on this but keep light on cloth material?????)]

[image]

[image: Cloth Physics 1]

[image: Cloth physics 2]

Comment: I think the weird edges are causing due to the solidify modifier. Maybe try simulating without that. If you want some thickness, add the modifier after the cloth simulation. Also, enabling self collision in the cloth settings will help.

Comment: I think @AshKB has some good feedback.  If removing the solidify is tearing the cloth, you might want to add solidify to your collision object, instead.  IMHO, the cloth looked "too thick" for silk.   But not a bad result thus far!